# Partial views in Bootstrap single page view & Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap's single page view template, specifically this one:
http://www.bootply.com/85746
I'm at the point where I have almost 500 lines of code in my view and I'm going to have many more.
Is there a way to create partial views with Angularjs where every section in the view will render from a partial view? I understand that I can only use one ng-view directive in a page so using it is not going to work. I could not find any solution for it on the web.

Thank you,
Mila

Comment: php require the files.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), which is a great solution to flexible routing with nested views.